# 400 Error while trying to call a PATCH API call in React even when the OPTIONS has passed OK

Tags: reactjs, api, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to use React to make API calls, I am able to successfully run GET and POST requests but when i ran PATCH, it return 400 error which is bad request. But i am able to run the same request successfully on Postman.

I have a feeling I am not passing the data in the right format, but the body and the headers are being passed in the same form as in the POST method which is working fine.

Also, the preflight request is being passed as OK (200) but the connection closes at PATCH request

This is my request, where the Id is being received from another component which is then passed to the API.

```
class AddPatients extends React.Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {message :''};
        console.log(this.props.list_id);
    }

   addPatients(url)
    {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('PATCH',url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Auth_key");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-OHP-Developer-API-Key", "API_Key ");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");


        let body = {
            data:
            [
                {
                   //record 1
                },
                {
                    //record 2
                }

            ]
        }
        const res = xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
        console.log('the response is', res);

    }

     onButtonClick()
    {
        var url =  'the url link/' + this.props.list_id;

        this.addPatients(url);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div> 
                <button onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}> Add patients to the list </button>
                {this.props.list_id}
                </div>
        );
    }


} 



export default AddPatients;
```

It has nothing to do with the OPTIONS request i think because it returns OPTIONS IN Allow-Methods options like:

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 18.236.241.179:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 31 Dec 2019 01:03:22 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,HEAD,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS,PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,x-requested-with,x-ohp-developer-api-key,content-type
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 336
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I resolved it. Was passing wring syntax in the JSON body, stupid mistake.